# How to do automated test with dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to automate a web application, which generates controls in pages dynamically, and the web controls's ID are never the same.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, MTM and Coded UI Tests. The application is being built with C# and Visual Studio 2012

The problem is that as the control's ID changes with every new run, the tests always fail.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Can't you specifically **assign** fixed ID's to those controls when you create them??

Comment: Coded UI tends to create search criteria with everything specified that can be specified. Often you can delete unwanted or unhelpful criteria. You may be able to just delete the control IDs from the search criteria.

Comment: At the moment I'm not being able to assign fixed ID's those controls. I've sent the request to dev team.

Comment: About search criteria, I'm watching on it, but it does not seem to be something very fast to do. Is it possible to be configured to remove them (ID, Name) for every new recorded step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the control id is changing you may use any other identifier to get the controls, like classname, tagname etc.
If classname is also dynamic then you can switch to tagname and get inner HTML of the control in order to confirm that the control is same as expected.
Then you would be able to work with the issue.

Comment: I was able to do it, but the problem is that I generate the scripts using de VS tool to record the steps, and visual studio generates the scripts automatically. Right after script generation I had to make the change manually to avoid using id and name.

As said, it worked, but it is not eficient. I'll keep searching

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure about this situation but I can given you an example and probably you can simulate this with the actual situation:

example: Like Loadrunner tool (used for performance testing), when it records the user action, it captures everything including all dynamic values of session id, so now if you replay your script it will fail because at time time of rerun, session ids are changed because of dynamic nature. 
How we handle this this: We take the page source and mark the left and right boundary between which dynamic value appears and store the dynamic value in some variable so next time you run, you don't ned to worry about dynamic value.

Not to confuse you, but similarly, you can take the page source, mark the right and left string, store the value between these marker in a variable and handle that. For marking you can use some regular expression ... hope this helps. !!

Comment: As said before, the problem is that I use the VS tool to record steps and generate the code automatically. The, I have to make the modifications manually and that is very slow.

Comment: "...I have to make the modifications manually and that is very slow...." and that is why you get paid the big bucks, for that expertise

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a button on your web app, and you want to click on that button.  In your situation where the ID is dynamic, I would **not** record the click on the button.  You need to create the button dynamically, and add search properties on the fly.  See code below.

**// Create instance of a html button as a test step.**

```
HtmlInputButton myButton = new HtmlInputButton(someUIMap.UISomeWindow.UISomeDocument);
```

**// Search for the button in the specified UI document as a test step.  Here we can search by the *DisplayText* property.**

```
myButton.SearchProperties.Add("DisplayText", "Your buttons Display Text");
```

**// Click the button if it exists.**

```
if(myButton.Exists)
{
   Mouse.Click(myButton);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helps, however, I did it modifying the search criteria generated by visual studio after the test has been recorded. Is not the best solution but it worked.